# JavaScript detect browser inactivity period when browser is idle with dynamic iframes in the page

Tags: javascript, iframe

This piece of code works very well to capture browser inactivity but I have Iframes in the page which dynamically included with javascript code. I want even consider the mouse move and keypress events in dynamic iframes as well. What kind of an extra piece code would solve this issue? I do not prefer to use any jquery browser idle plugin.

Thanks in advance!!.

```
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});
function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the iframes on a domains under your control? You cannot handle events for an iframe on a different domain.

Comment: The domains are under my control

Comment: This works but for already loaded iframes not for dynamic ones. 
$('iframe').contents().keypress(function(){console.log('iframe keypress event fired');});

Answer (score 0):

This works but for alrady loaded iframes not for dynamic ones. How to make it work for dynamically loaded iframes.

```
$('iframe').contents().keypress(function(){console.log('iframe keypress event fired');});

$('iframe').contents().mousemove(function(){console.log('iframe mouse move event fired');});
```